# Mock Unit tests for Linq statements in .Net core 2.2 always return null

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-core, mocking, asp.net-core-2.2

I know lots of mocking questions are asked, but none worked with me.

I'm trying to write a unit test for a service I have. The service have the following line of code

```
    var assignments = await _assignmentRepository.WhereAsync(as => as.DepartmentId == departmentId);
```

Here's the implementation of `WhereAsync` method:

```
    public async Task<List<T>> WhereAsync(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression)
    {
        return await _dbContext.Set<T>().Where(expression).ToListAsync();
    }
```

Here's my mock test statement (`listAssignments` is a predefined variable):

```
     _assignmentRepository.Setup(rep => rep.WhereAsync(as => It.IsAny<bool>())).ReturnsAsync(listAssignments);
```

I know that we can't Mock `Where` and `FirstOrDefault` methods, but isn't there a way to mock my web service `WhereAsync` method??

Comment: The big question is: What do you really want to test? Usually you mock the repository, not the DbContext, so your implementation of the repository doesn't matter at all, you mock the repository interface. And Unit Testing EF Core is pointless. You unit test **your** code, not others code

Comment: I'm testing a service. The service receive a department Id as parameter and return the assignments in this department. So I'm executing a `WhereAsync` implemented in assignment repository, where `assignment.departmentId` equal `Id` sent by parameter.

Comment: Thats not a unit test. In a unit test you replace the call to the **repository implementation** with a mock which returns the result **you desire/require** to the the objects logic **relying** on the repository

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `Tseng` mentioned in the comment above. We don't mock the `DbContext`, we mock the repository itself.

So I used the `InMemoryDatabase` testing. Added some data to my in-memory database which made my `DbContext` return the data I want.

```
        var mapOptions = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MapViewerContext>()
               .UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
               .Options;
        var identityOptions = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<AppIdentityDbContext>()
            .UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
            .Options;
        var mapContext = new MapViewerContext(_configuration.Object, mapOptions);
        var appIdentityContext = new AppIdentityDbContext(_configuration.Object, identityOptions);
```